# How to change the lines between two points from curved to straight lines with one angle point

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, svg

What i need

[image: what i need]

Current example : http://jsfiddle.net/2ecsjomz/5/

Notes:

- a specific left/right pair will never change places, `"left drag"` will always stay on the left or the `"right drag"`
- a single angle point needs to be formed between two points
- the line starting from the "left drag" needs to be horizontal
- if it helps i do not need the points to be draggable, its ok to have specific coordinates.
- it needs to generate lines between two html elements ( same as example )

Comment: Sidenote: This is a valid question, just bad formatting. Hiding behind screen and giving out `-1` for every small mistake is just plain dumb. A better way is to spend a few minutes to correct the article like `Mr LeBeau` (a thumbs up from me)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the path coding to this one below:

```
        // Build the path decription
        p = "M" + pt1x + "," + pt1y +
            " L" + (pt1x+pt2x)/2 + "," + pt1y +
            " L" + pt2x + "," + pt2y ;
```

Comment: Noted, moved sidenote: to comments section above

Comment: Excelent, thank you very much Captain, it's exactly what i needed!