# Draw arrow in svg path dynamically is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

```js
var Belay = (function () {
    var settings = {
        strokeColor: '#fff',
        strokeWidth: 2,
        opacity: 1,
        fill: 'none',
        animate: true,
        animationDirection: 'right',
        animationDuration: .75
    };
    var me = {};

    me.init = function (initObj) {
        if (initObj) {
            $.each(initObj, function (index, value) {
                //TODO validation on settings
                settings[index] = value;
            });
        }
    }

    me.set = function (prop, val) {
        //TODO validate
        settings[prop] = val;
    }

    me.on = function (el1, el2) {
        var $el1 = $(el1);
        var $el2 = $(el2);
        if ($el1.length && $el2.length) {
            var svgheight, p, svgleft, svgtop, svgwidth

            var el1pos = $(el1).offset();
            var el2pos = $(el2).offset();

            var el1H = $(el1).outerHeight();
            var el1W = $(el1).outerWidth();

            var el2H = $(el2).outerHeight();
            var el2W = $(el2).outerWidth();

            var node1X = Math.round(el1pos.left + el1W);
            var node2X = Math.round(el2pos.left);
            var overlapping = node1X >= node2X;
            
            var svgwidth = Math.abs(node2X - node1X);
            var svgleft = Math.min(node1X, node2X);

            var node1Y = Math.round(el1pos.top + el1H / 2);
            var node2Y = Math.round(el2pos.top + el1H / 2);
            
            var svgheight = Math.abs(node1Y - node2Y);
            var svgtop = Math.min(node1Y, node2Y);

            var pt1x = node1X - svgleft;
            var pt1y = node1Y - svgtop + settings.strokeWidth;
            var pt2x = node2X - svgleft;
            var pt2y = node2Y - svgtop + settings.strokeWidth;

            // cpt is the length of the control point vector
            // variew with distance netween boxes
            var cpt = Math.round(svgwidth * Math.min(svgheight / 300, 1));

            if (overlapping) {
                // Need to widen the svg because otherwise the bezier control
                // points (and hence the curve) will extend outside it.
                svgleft -= cpt;
                svgwidth += 2 * cpt;
                pt1x += cpt;
                pt2x += cpt;
            }

            // Build the path decription
            p = "M" + pt1x + "," + pt1y +
            " L" + (pt1x + pt2x) / 8 + "," + pt1y +
            " L" + (pt1x + pt2x) / 8 + "," + pt2y //+
            " L" + (pt2x) / 1.03 + "," + pt2y +
            " L" + (pt2x) / 1.03 + "," + (pt2y - 5) +
            " L" + pt2x + "," + pt2y +
            " L" + (pt2x) / 1.03 + "," + (pt2y + 5) +
            " L" + (pt2x) / 1.03 + "," + pt2y;

            //ugly one-liner
            $ropebag = $('#ropebag').length ? $('#ropebag') : $('body').append($("<div id='ropebag' />")).find('#ropebag');

            var svgnode = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');
            var defs = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', "defs");
            var marker = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', "marker");
            var path = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', "path");

            marker.setAttributeNS(null,"id","arrow");
            marker.setAttributeNS(null,"markerWidth","13");
            marker.setAttributeNS(null,"markerHeight","13");
            marker.setAttributeNS(null,"refX","2");
            marker.setAttributeNS(null,"refY","7");
            marker.setAttributeNS(null,"markerUnits","userSpaceOnUse");
            path.setAttributeNS(null,"d","M2,2 L2,13 L8,7 L2,2");

      marker.appendChild(path);
            defs.appendChild(marker);

            var newpath = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', "path");
            newpath.setAttributeNS(null, "d", p);
            newpath.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke", settings.strokeColor);
            newpath.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke-width", settings.strokeWidth);
            newpath.setAttributeNS(null, "opacity", settings.opacity);
            newpath.setAttributeNS(null, "fill", settings.fill);
            newpath.setAttributeNS(null, "marker-end", "url(#arrow)");

           svgnode.appendChild(newpath);
           svgnode.appendChild(defs);
          
            $(svgnode).css({
                left: svgleft,
                top: svgtop - settings.strokeWidth,
                position: 'absolute',
                width: svgwidth,
                height: svgheight + settings.strokeWidth * 2,
                minHeight: '20px',
                'pointer-events': 'none'
            });
            $ropebag.append(svgnode);
            if (settings.animate) {
                // THANKS to http://jakearchibald.com/2013/animated-line-drawing-svg/
                var pl = newpath.getTotalLength();
                // Set up the starting positions
                newpath.style.strokeDasharray = pl + ' ' + pl;

                if (settings.animationDirection == 'right') {
                    newpath.style.strokeDashoffset = pl;
                } else {
                    newpath.style.strokeDashoffset = -pl;
                }

                // Trigger a layout so styles are calculated & the browser
                // picks up the starting position before animating
                // WON'T WORK IN IE. If you want that, use requestAnimationFrame to update instead of CSS animation
                newpath.getBoundingClientRect();
                newpath.style.transition = newpath.style.WebkitTransition = 'stroke-dashoffset ' + settings.animationDuration + 's ease-in-out';
                // Go!
                newpath.style.strokeDashoffset = '0';
            }
        }
    }

    me.off = function () {
        $("#ropebag").empty();
    }

    return me;
}());


/***********************  Custom JavaScript **********************************/


$(document).ready(function () {


    $(".draggable").draggable({
        drag: function (event, ui) {
            Belay.off();
            drawConnectors();
        }
    });



    function drawConnectors() {
        $(".parent").each(function () {
            var theID = this.id;
            $("." + theID).each(function (i, e) {
                var rand = Math.random() * .7 + .3;
                Belay.set('animationDuration', rand)
                Belay.on($("#" + theID), e)
            });
        })
    }

    $(window).resize(function () {
        Belay.off();
        drawConnectors();
    });

    Belay.init({
        strokeWidth: 1
    });
    Belay.set('strokeColor', '#999');
    drawConnectors();
});
```

```css
.row{
margin-top:2in;
}

.box{
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="pull-left ">
                <div class="parent draggable box" id="parent1">Left drag</div>
            </div>

            <div class="pull-right">
                <div class="child parent1 draggable box">Right drag</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Hi as per this example [how-to-change-the-lines-between-two-points-from-curved-to-straight-lines-with-on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31587191/how-to-change-the-lines-between-two-points-from-curved-to-straight-lines-with-on) how to draw arrow at the end of the path dynamically

can someone tell me what is wrong in adding marker end in my code

```js
var Belay = (function () 
{
    var settings = {
        strokeColor: 'red',
        strokeWidth: 2,
        opacity: 1,
        fill: 'none',
        animate: true,
        animationDirection: 'right',
        animationDuration: .75
    };
    var me = {};

    me.init = function (initObj) {
        if (initObj) {
            $.each(initObj, function (index, value) {
                //TODO validation on settings
                settings[index] = value;
            });
        }
    }

    me.set = function (prop, val) {
        //TODO validate
        settings[prop] = val;
    }

    me.on = function (el1, el2) {
        var $el1 = $(el1);
        var $el2 = $(el2);
        if ($el1.length && $el2.length) {
            var svgheight, p, svgleft, svgtop, svgwidth

            var el1pos = $(el1).offset();
            var el2pos = $(el2).offset();

            var el1H = $(el1).outerHeight();
            var el1W = $(el1).outerWidth();

            var el2H = $(el2).outerHeight();
            var el2W = $(el2).outerWidth();

            var node1X = Math.round(el1pos.left + el1W);
            var node2X = Math.round(el2pos.left);
            var overlapping = node1X >= node2X;

            var svgwidth = Math.abs(node2X - node1X);
            var svgleft = Math.min(node1X, node2X);

            var node1Y = Math.round(el1pos.top + el1H / 2);
            var node2Y = Math.round(el2pos.top + el1H / 2);

            var svgheight = Math.abs(node1Y - node2Y);
            var svgtop = Math.min(node1Y, node2Y);

            var pt1x = node1X - svgleft;
            var pt1y = node1Y - svgtop + settings.strokeWidth;
            var pt2x = node2X - svgleft;
            var pt2y = node2Y - svgtop + settings.strokeWidth;

            // cpt is the length of the control point vector
            // variew with distance netween boxes
            var cpt = Math.round(svgwidth * Math.min(svgheight / 300, 1));

            if (overlapping) {
                // Need to widen the svg because otherwise the bezier control
                // points (and hence the curve) will extend outside it.
                svgleft -= cpt;
                svgwidth += 2 * cpt;
                pt1x += cpt;
                pt2x += cpt;
            }

            p = "M" + pt1x + "," + pt1y +
            " L" + (pt1x + pt2x) / 8 + "," + pt1y +
            " L" + (pt1x + pt2x) / 8 + "," + pt2y +
            " L" + (pt2x) / 1.03 + "," + pt2y +
            " L" + (pt2x) / 1.03 + "," + (pt2y - 5) +
            " L" + pt2x + "," + pt2y +
            " L" + (pt2x) / 1.03 + "," + (pt2y + 5) +
            " L" + (pt2x) / 1.03 + "," + pt2y;

            //ugly one-liner
            $ropebag = $('#ropebag').length ? $('#ropebag') : $('body').append($("<div id='ropebag' />")).find('#ropebag');

            var svgnode = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');

            //try
            var defs = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', "defs");
            var marker = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', "marker");
            var path = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', "path");

            marker.setAttributeNS(null,"id","arrow");
            marker.setAttributeNS(null,"markerWidth",10);
            marker.setAttributeNS(null,"markerHeight",10);
            marker.setAttributeNS(null,"refX",0);
            marker.setAttributeNS(null,"refY",5);
            marker.setAttributeNS(null,"viewbox","0 0 10 10");
            marker.setAttributeNS(null,"orient","auto");
            marker.setAttributeNS(null,"markerUnits","strokeWidth");
            
            path.setAttributeNS(null,"d","M 0 0 L 10 5 L 0 10");
            ////try
            marker.appendChild(path);
            defs.appendChild(marker);

            var newpath = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', "path");
            newpath.setAttributeNS(null, "d", p);
            newpath.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke", settings.strokeColor);
            newpath.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke-width", settings.strokeWidth);
            newpath.setAttributeNS(null, "opacity", settings.opacity);
            newpath.setAttributeNS(null, "fill", settings.fill);
            newpath.setAttributeNS(null, "marker-end", "url(#arrow)");

            newpath.appendChild(defs);


            svgnode.appendChild(newpath);
            //for some reason, adding a min-height to the svg div makes the lines appear more correctly.
            $(svgnode).css({
                left: svgleft,
                top: svgtop - settings.strokeWidth,
                position: 'absolute',
                width: svgwidth,
                height: svgheight + settings.strokeWidth * 2,
                minHeight: '20px',
                'pointer-events': 'none'
            });
            $ropebag.append(svgnode);
            if (settings.animate) {
                // THANKS to http://jakearchibald.com/2013/animated-line-drawing-svg/
                var pl = newpath.getTotalLength();
                // Set up the starting positions
                newpath.style.strokeDasharray = pl + ' ' + pl;

                if (settings.animationDirection == 'right') {
                    newpath.style.strokeDashoffset = pl;
                } else {
                    newpath.style.strokeDashoffset = -pl;
                }

                // Trigger a layout so styles are calculated & the browser
                // picks up the starting position before animating
                // WON'T WORK IN IE. If you want that, use requestAnimationFrame to update instead of CSS animation
                newpath.getBoundingClientRect();
                newpath.style.transition = newpath.style.WebkitTransition = 'stroke-dashoffset ' + settings.animationDuration + 's ease-in-out';
                // Go!
                newpath.style.strokeDashoffset = '0';
            }
        }
    }

    me.off = function () 
 {
        $("#ropebag").empty();
    }

    return me;
} ());

function drawConnectors() 
{
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't seem to be appending `newpath` to anything.

Also you are appending `defs` to `newpath`. I'm not sure that works (I've never tried it). You should probably avoid doing that.  Append the defs to the SVG instead.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. Now i updated my code can you help me out in this?

Comment: What is your issue with the end marker?  It is being drawn correctly on the end of the line.  You just can't see the bottom half of it because it is off he bottom of the SVG. The quick fix for that would be to add `overflow: none` to the SVG CSS.  The only remaining problem is that you aren't calculating the width of the SVG properly. It is not going all the way to the "Right drag" box.